# How to make barplots with text above the bars that always will be inside the axes?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, pgfplots

I am making bar plots (`xbar`) in `pgfplots` and adding text/numbers on top of each bar by using the `nodes near coords` command in the `axis` environment. The x-axis is by purpose not given any value for the parameter `xmax` in order to make the tallest bar dynamically determine the maximum x-value used in the axis (the line `xmax=100` is commented out). However, the extent of the text/numbers on top of each bar is not taken into account when the max value along the x-axis is determined by TikZ. In my example, the name "Steve" on top of the second bar from above is overlapping with the right y-axis. How do I prevent this in a way that will fix the problem  independently of the x values in the `data.dat` file?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
Age-interval        Y-Position         Score        Name
20-30               1                  15           Peter
30-40               2                  98           Jeff
40-50               3                  121          Steve
50-60               4                  24           John 
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\makeatletter
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel={Test score},
    xbar,     
    bar width=2pt,
    ytick=data,
    width=8 cm,
    height=5 cm,
    xmin=-1,
   % xmax = 100,
    xticklabel pos = upper,
    tick align = outside,
    yticklabel pos=left, 
    yticklabels from table={data.dat}{Age-interval},
    ylabel={Age intervals (yr)},
    nodes near coords,
    every node near coord/.append style={anchor=west},
    point meta=explicit symbolic
]
\addplot table [
    y=Y-Position,
    x=Score,
    meta=Name
] {data.dat};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set `enlarge x limits={upper, value=0.2}`, which will increase the upper x limit by 20% of the plot's x range, so as long as none of your labels are wider than 20% of the plot width, you should be fine. If you have longer labels, you might need to choose a different value.

[image]

If you really want an automatic solution that will accommodate any label length, here's one solution. I wrote a new key called `accommodate labels` that takes the name of a table and the name of a column containing the labels as arguments, and then computes the `enlarge x limits` value. This assumes that the `width` of the plot is set manually (otherwise the value is not available), and that `scale only axis` is activated (otherwise the `width` refers to the whole figure, not just the axis area).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
Age-interval        Y-Position         Score        Name
20-30               1                  15           Peter
30-40               2                  98           Jeff
40-50               3                  121          LoooooooongJohnSilver
50-60               4                  24           John 
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotsset{
    accommodate labels/.code 2 args={
        \newlength{\myl}
        \pgfplotstableread{#1}\data
        \def\largestlength{0}
        \pgfplotstableforeachcolumnelement{#2}\of\data\as\cell{
            \settowidth{\myl}{\pgfinterruptpicture\cell\endpgfinterruptpicture}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\largestlength{max(\the\myl,\largestlength)}
        }
        \pgfplotsset{
            enlarge x limits={
                upper,              value=1/(1-(\largestlength+4pt)/\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/width})-1
            }
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel={Test score},
    xbar,     
    bar width=2pt,
    ytick=data,scale only axis,
    width=6cm,
    height=5cm,
    xmin=-1,
    accommodate labels={data.dat}{Name},
    xticklabel pos = upper,
    tick align = outside,
    yticklabel pos=left, 
    yticklabels from table={data.dat}{Age-interval},
    ylabel={Age intervals (yr)},
    nodes near coords,
    every node near coord/.append style={anchor=west},
    point meta=explicit symbolic
]
\addplot table [
    y=Y-Position,
    x=Score,
    meta=Name
] {data.dat};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Espen Consider removing the right y and upper x axis lines. You don't need them, as this is not a diagram where the ticks help you in accurately reading a certain value. In Jake's example, the x axis has eight labels, while you only have 4 data points. You could add the actual value to each name and get a more precise diagram that way.

Comment: @Jake Thaks for your answer, it works :) But this solution is still somewhat manual. I am working on a code for automatically generating reports and would like a dynamic solution that takes care of the length of the names on top of each bar.

Comment: @Christoph Thanks for your answer. Yes you are right in this simple expample, but my barplots are combined into larger diagrames where I need this structure. Anyhow: the names on top of the bars still may protude outside the leftmost y-axis regardless of if this axis is drawn or not.

Comment: @EspenDonali: I've edited my answer to include a different approach.

Comment: @Jake thanks a lot! Your answer seems very promissing, I will test it out :)